# Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement while trying to insert into mysql database using flask application

Tags: python, mysql

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08xvy.png)Actually I am trying to create flask web application in which, I wanted to store my input values from html webpage into MySQL database, but am getting error as Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement when calling my insert function.
Please find my code

```
import mysql.connector as conn

def insert_records(name,email,location,salary,band):
    con=conn.connect(host='localhost',user='root',password='my password',database="my database")
    cur=con.cursor()
    sql="""insert into emp1.emp(Name,Email,Location,Salary,Band) values (%s,%s,%s,%d,%s)"""
    val=(name,email,location,salary,band)
    cur.execute(sql,val)
    con.commit()
    con.close()
```

Comment: where is the error?

Comment: I think they all need to be %s

Look at the example in the documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html, even if a column is a integer, they use %s.

Comment: @Bemwa Malak please check , now I  have attached the error image also

Comment: @BrianKarabinchak  Thanks lot... finally my issue is resolved.... now I can move forward for  remaining

Answer (score 1):

You need to use %s for every argument per the documentation - they use %s for strings, integers, datetimes, etc.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html